# Практический пример нестатического класса со статическими членами

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Готовлю материал по статическим членам класса и не могу придумать нормальный, не высосанный из пальца и понятный пример нестатического класса с одним или парой статических членов.

Всем огромное спасибо за ответы, примеры правда интересные, но я хотел очень простой пример для "самых маленьких", для студентов 1го и 2го курса начинающих изучать базовые элементы языка. Я понимаю, всё это очень хорошие примеры, но у студентов возникнет много вопросов и они потребует понятного аргумента по каждому такому ответу, но без хороших знаний и практики все мои ответы будут для них пустым звуком.

Я принял решение использовать такой простой но всё же синтетический пример, да он потоко не безопасен, да и вообще корявый, но для первого знакомства с понятием статического члена класса сойдёт (ну я так думаю):

```
class Student
{
    // автоматический счётчик
    static private int autoInc = 1;


    public int Id {get;} // свойство доступное на чтение
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Student()
    {
        // присваивание уникального идентификатора
        Id = autoInc;
        // инкремент счётчика
        autoInc++;        
    } 
}
```

Comment: `String.Empty`, `Application.Current`, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` и еще миллион примеров.

Comment: Мой косяк.
Я забыл упомянуть, что пример нужен для студентов 1го -2го курсов которые только начали изучать базовые элементы языка.
Все примеры приведённые в ответах классные, но не для уровня начинающих.

Comment: 1) Добавляйте код в вопрос, в комментах он нечитаем 2) Ваш счетчик не потокобезопасный

Comment: имхо, ничего реально полезного и проще, чем `String.Empty` я бы наверное не смог придумать.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что у студентов возникнут вопрос: зачем так делать?
Такое трудно аргументированно ответить начинающему.

И у меня проблема с кодом в комментах)  Думал тут применима разметка markdown, но у меня не получилось)

Comment: ну ок, можете пояснить назначение `int.Parse(...)` - если студенты и это не поймут, то я не знаю что предложить :)

Comment: Думаю, что поймут) Добавлю как пример с пометкой: пример из платформы dotnet.
Спасибо!

Comment: Пример из вопроса практически один в один совпадает с тем что было в одной из моих старых игр. Айдишник должен был быть уникальным и отражать порядок создания объектов. Так что это хороший пример, я считаю.

Answer (score 4):

Статические члены нужны, например, при реализации [паттерна "Синглтон"](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.3.php):

```
class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton()
    {}

    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример из текущего проекта. Имеется класс, описывающий смену статуса документа, и имеется несколько допустимых переходов:

```
public class StatusTransition
{
    public Status From { get; }
    public Status To { get; }

    protected StatusTransition(Status from, Status to)
        => (From, To) = (from, to);

    public static readonly StatusTransition NewToIssued = new StatusTransition(Status.New, Status.Issued);
    public static readonly StatusTransition IssuedToActive = new StatusTransition(Status.Issued, Status.Active);
    ...
}
```

Опционально конструктор может быть открытым, могут быть добавлены методы `GetHashCode()` и др.